# How to specify Filename with blanks in Subversion command prompt

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm trying to execute a subversion related command line argument.

However it appears that it doesnt take the file name has blanks

Ex: User Guide Version 1.0.doc

I tried enclosing in double quotes 
**"User Guide Version 1.0.doc"**

and within square braces '[]' in vain 
**[User Guide Version 1.0.doc]**

Am i missing something

Comment: Are you trying to target the local file, or is this an url?

Answer (score 5):

On windows cmd prompt, you need to use double quotes and on unixes you can use either.

> svn add "my file"

and

> C:\kev>svn co file:///kev/dummy dummy2
>
> A    dummy2\User Guide Version 1.0.doc
>
> Checked out revision 1.

works perfectly on windows for me. Could you supply svn output to help if you're still having problems?

Answer (score 1):

On the command line, using single quotes should do the trick: `'file name'`.

**Update:** The second argument to `svn co` must be a PATH, not a filename!

> $ svn help co
>
> checkout (co): Check out
> a working copy from a repository.
> usage: checkout URL[@REV]... [PATH]
>
> If specified, REV determines in
> which revision the URL is first
> looked up.
>
> If PATH is omitted, the basename of
> the URL will be used as   the
> destination. If multiple URLs are
> given each will be checked   out into
> a sub-directory of PATH, with the name
> of the sub-directory   being the
> basename of the URL.

Comment: this is specifically for subversion. Im unable to check out a file because it has blanks in it. Enclosing in Single quotes also fails :(

Comment: @this-Me: COuld you please show us the full commandline invocation that you are using?

Comment: So dumb of me ... I thought i had to give the path and not the file name. But is it possible in SVN to checkout a file ?? What I mean is in SVN i can start making changes (after a resynchronize) for a file without actually explicitly specifying to checkout the file.

Comment: @this-Me
Remember that SVN needs a working copy, that is a directory where it can store the metadata. So if you want to work on file, including future commits, you need to checkout the directory. If you just want to LOOK at a file, you could use 'svn cat' (but then you can't commit).

Comment: I think i phrased it very bad in my earlier comment.Am aware that SVN needs a working copy to make the changes and commit. Since i have been working in Tortoise SVN for quite some time, i see that all i need to do is just get a latest copy of a file and then start modifying(without calling a checkout specifically ...usually in a code editor) and then am ready to commit the changes..... But i what i really meant was... Is it possible in SVN to specifically call a CHECKOUT operation on a FILE ?

Answer (score 1):

You should simply do this:

```
svn checkout https://vatsa.com/svn/dcs/branches/doc
```

This will create a local working copy folder named "doc" in the current working directory.

Your mistake was that you gave a **file name** as the last argument. You can only checkout folders, not individual files.

The first argument after `svn checkout` is the URL of the folder in the repository. The second argument is optional, and is used to specify the name of the local working copy folder in case you don't want to use the same folder name as in the repository or if you want to specify a location other than in the current working directory.

Finally, seeing a branch named "doc" makes me wonder whether you've misunderstood what branches are for.  See the explanation [What's a Branch](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.branchmerge.whatis.html) in the SVN book. Branches are for concurrently maintaining different copies of your whole project, not for organizing different components (like source and documentation) of the same project.

Comment: Hi Wim Thanks i am aware of the Branches are for maintaining different copies of a project. The URL was just for demo purpose only. When i type "svn help checkout" on the command line. I see that the usage as "checkout URL[@REV]...[PATH]". So i assume that i need to specify a path alongwith the URL to the checkout command.